# Acquiring sensor data with a raspberry pi in the kilo samples per second range

Tags: multithreading, raspberry-pi, real-time

I have a raspberry pi and a spi sensor acquiring data at a rate of that could vary between 2kS/s and 20kS/s.

My goal is to get that data and push it on a MQTT server that will be displayed in real time, no data loss is acceptable.

To know that data is ready, the chip has an interrupt pin. A friend I'm working with used that pin as an interrupt for the Pi.

I'm foreseeing some problems here :

The routine executed by the interruption will store the data in a circular buffer, that buffer will be used by another thread and thus they must synchronize their access to it.

If the thread in question is preempted by the OS during the small time it's locking the buffer I can either have :

- A deadlock if the interruption happens during that time and cannot be preempted
- If I disable the interruption and the thread gets preempted at that moment I will likely lose data.

Questions are :

- Am I right in fearing that a 500us period requirement for a task will cause problems ?
- Is it feasible in python ? Can I tell the scheduler that during a critical section nothing can be preempted ?
- Should I migrate to a real time os and use C++ ?

Thank you in advance for the time anyone would spent answering

Comment: Assuming a circular buffer of data, you can shove data in before updating the 'front' pointer/index, so that if the thread is extracting data behind the index, everything should be fine:)  You may need a volatile qualifier in the index and, possibly, a memory barrier, but you should be OK without explicit locking.  It's a bit difficult to suggest more without details of the data/protocol.

Comment: 'Am I right in fearing that a 500us period requirement for a task will cause problems ?'.... what task?  Presumably, the consuming thread will be made ready when the interrupt handler has loaded data/protocol unit into the buffer, by signaling a semaphore or the like.  Assuming that the system is not overloaded with ready threads, I would hope that the consumer would be in there, emptying buffer data, in much less than 500us:)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a real-time thread pinned to an isolated CPU with disabled interrupts to access the pins. Caveat - you'll need a user-space GPIO and SPI drivers in order to do this, to avoid any system calls in your real-time thread.

With a circular buffer large enough you don't need any sync in between writer and consumer. Writer only updates the write pointer, reader updates the read pointer, and there is no problem if reader gets an outdated write pointer value - it'll catch up the next cycle. The beauty of circular buffers is exactly in this lock-free operation.